# oracle connection in r

Tags: r, oracle

hi folks I can connect to oracle through R no problem using the following code:

```
library(RODBC)

channel <- odbcConnect(dsn = "xxxx", uid = "xxxx", pwd = "xxxx")
odbcGetInfo(channel)## CHECKS CONNECTION TO ORACLE


COMPANIES <- sqlFetch(channel, "COMPANIES")
COMPANIES_EQUIPMENT <-sqlFetch(channel, "COMPANIES_EQUIPMENT")
EQUIPMENT_SENSORS  <-sqlFetch(channel, "EQUIPMENT_SENSORS")


odbcClose(channel) ## CLOSES odbc CONNECTION
```

when I fetch the first data table "COMPANIES" , no issue but this means running the code just to fetch this data frame, the problem is that when I run the above code to fetch all 3 data frames: 
COMPANIES,
COMPANIES_EQUIPMENT,
EQUIPMENT_SENSORS
my R script just hangs up, I have tried to run each fetch statement individually, and they all work but when run together my script just hangs up any ideas?

Not sure if problem is R, New laptop or Oracle, oracle seems ok as can connect no issue but is there a data limit maybe allowed etc...

I am using Oracle Instantclient 11.2 to connect my laptop windows 7 Professional to Oracle, RStudio Version 1.0.143

thanks

Nigel

Comment: Does it hang if you fetch two of the three tables? Or the same table twice? Or try doing a select with a small limit (eg 10 rows)? Or opening and closing the odbc connection between fetches?

Comment: yes I have tried opening and closing between connections this also hangs up, also tried opening two files opened no issue but when I try three freezes or hangs, I will write some code later to try and select the top 20 or so records from each tables

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using `sqlQuery` instead of `sqlFetch`?

```
COMPANIES <- sqlQuery(channel, "SELECT * FROM COMPANIES")
```

you might need to replace the `*` by the names of the variables.

I personnally use RJDBC to connect to Oracle:

```
driverClass="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
classPath="<PATH_TO_INSTANTCLIENT>/instantclient_12_1/ojdbc6‌​.jar"
connectPath="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<HOST>:<PORT>/<DB_NAME>" 
jdbcDriver <- RJDBC::JDBC(driverClass, classPath)
jdbcConnection <- RJDBC::dbConnect(jdbcDriver, connectPath, dbuser, dbpass)
```

Comment: Hi Aneuraz, thank you, I have tried sqlQuery, does the same, will try and find a connection string for RJDBC and will give that ago

Comment: Hiya Aneuraz, I have tried all above it seems to be Oracle is slow at connecting through RODBC, So please could you give me an example of your connection string for RJDBC IF possible

Comment: please, see my edited answer for an example @NigelGriffin.

Comment: Hi Aneurezm I have tried the connection for the RJDC, below is my code I use but get the following error:  Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found

Comment: the code I used:                                                                 library(RJDBC)
library(RODBC)
  driverClass="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
  classPath="C:/instantclient_11_2/ojdbc6‌​.jar"
  connectPath="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<xxxxxx>:<xxxx>/<xxxxx>" 
  jdbcDriver <- RJDBC::JDBC(driverClass, classPath)


  jdbcConnection <- RJDBC::dbConnect(jdbcDriver,xxxx, xxxxx)

Comment: I don't remember exactly but you might need to define some environment variables for your instant client install.